# Are the sentences same in terms of meaning?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Have pity on him.

Have pity toward him.

Have pity for him.

As all the preposition are seeming same, I am a bit confused.

Comment: The idiom in English is: to have pity **on** someone.

Comment: Can i say as above sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment by Lambie points out, the fixed phrase in English (I wouldn't call it an idiom) is "*Have pity **on** him.*" This dates at last to the usage in the King James Bible, and perhaps further back. It is by far the most common form in general usage.

I sometimes hear "*Have pity **for** him.*" or more often something like "Have pity for the poor." or "Have pity for the homeless."

I very rarely recall hearing "Have pity **toward** him."

That said, all three are grammatically valid and would be understood by a fluent speaker. The meaning is much the same for each.

As a matter of usage, perhaps "*Have pity **on** him.*"  is most used when the person addressed is in a position to do some act of pity. In particular, that form is used in prayers addressed to God, who is presumed able to do any such act of pity. In contrast, I think  "*Have pity **for** him.*" is asking the listener for an emotion, bur perhaps not any action.